# Using multiple local ips (127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3) with ssh tunnels

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have 3 servers (a, b, c) and each of them need an ssh tunnel to port 4000 of another 2 instances.

I used to assign ports like 4001 goes to port 4000 on instance B and 4002 goes to 4000 on instance C, but it seems that using local ips 127.0.0/24 would be much less confusing, e.g. put `127.0.0.2 instance-a` to `/etc/hosts`, then use `ssh -L instance-a:4000:localhost:4000 instance-a.domain.com`. Does this approach bear any negative effects? Should it be used?

Comment: Not sure how you want to limit ssh to a specific loopback address when setting up the tunnels. Without that you obviously get a "already in use" conflict.

Comment: Just tried `ssh -L 127.0.0.2:5000:localhost:5000 server` and `ssh -L 127.0.0.3:5000:localhost:5001 server` at the same time - worked as expected - nc 127.0.0.2 5000 sent to remote port 5000 and nc 127.0.0.3 5000 sent to remote port 5001

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was not aware of the fact that you _can_ actually specify an explicit bind address. Obviously in that case things work. So I do not see a reason against that approach.